# Trouble with special cyrillic extension sign (Ge with middle hook = U+0494)

Tags: input-encodings, cyrillic

The problem should be clear from the title. I have been trying to type this special character for a while. So far, anything failed. The weird this is: I can find this sign in kile right at "Cyrillic Characters" as `\cyrghk`. It tells me, that I need `[koi8-r]inputenc`, `[T2C]fontenc`, `mathtext` and `[russian]{babel}`, which is all I need for the standard russian characters. 
Actually I can type most russian characters like `\cyrb` and so on. It also works with `[utf8]inputenc` and without `mathtext`. I don't know why.
However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
\cyrghk unavailable in encoding T2A. ...\cyrghk
```

So far, I am using "5" as a work-around, which seems to be what Yakut people do as well, when they text on smartphones, etc. Any better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use the `fontspec` package on either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default encoding for the character as T2C:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2C,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrghk}{T2C}

\begin{document}

ҕ \cyrghk

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use KOI8-R, UTF-8 is much better.

Comment: Definitely want to second the recommendation to encode new documents in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

T2A is not T2C. If you load russian, T2A is the default encoding. You could change to T2C:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2C]{fontenc}
\def\cyrillicencoding{T2C}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document} 
\cyrghk
\end{document}
```

or you could locally switch only for the one symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2C,T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{T2C}\selectfont\cyrghk}
\end{document}
```

or use an unicode engine (lualatex, xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
ҕ
\end{document}
```